# Authorization failures when publishing to Gitlab Package Registry

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

On my self-hosted Gitlab I am trying to publish a JAR file, to a Maven package registry. Following the Gitlab documentation and various instructions found in tutorials, I made necessary additions and changes to my pom.xml file which are shown below:

```
      .
     .
     .
  <repositories>
     <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://git.solishome.net/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
     </repository>
  </repositories>
  <distributionManagement>
     <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://git.solishome.net/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
     </repository>
     <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://git.solishome.net/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
     </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

I also created an access token and placed its value into a settings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
   <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
         <httpHeaders>
            <property>
               <name>Private-Token</name>
               <value><My_Project_Access_Token></value>
            </property>
         </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
   </server>
</settings>
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt the deployment, I am getting "unauthorized" (401) errors:

```
[INFO] Total time:  4.199 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-01T03:05:03Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project resultclass: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.factor3.libs:resultclass:pom:1.2.0 from/to gitlab-maven (https://git.solishome.net/api/v4/projects/4/packages/maven): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

From what I can understand from the documentation, the access token is supposed to authorize the access. My token doesn't seem to, despite the fact that when I created it I gave it all privileges -- including repository write privileges. So why am I getting unauthorized errors???

Can anyone help with this? How can I get my JAR file into the repository?